# How to get Gltf data from a xeogl scene?

Tags: reactjs, viewer, gltf

I am trying to get specific Gltf-data such as the mesh name (as written in the .gltf file) when clicking on a mesh inside a 3D viewer in a React web application. For the viewer i am using [Xeogl](https://xeogl.org/) from xeolabs, which is able to display a gltf file in a html-canvas element. However, the only data I am able to extract from the interface is data from Xeogl-parameters (eg. scene, material, children,... see figure 2).

I seem to be unable to get any of the metadata found inside the .gltf file itself.

Does anybody know how the gltf-data is integrated in the Xeogl-model, or how I can find the respective gltf data from the .gltf file when clicking on a mesh?
Thanks in advance!

**Figure 1:** *The Click Event*

[image: The click event]

**Figure 2:** *the outcome we get from event with xeogl data (left), the outcome we want from .gltf file (right)*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a `handleNode` callback during loading of the gltf model. See: http://xeogl.org/docs/classes/GLTFModel.html and look for the `handleNode` function.

In that callback, you can define an `actions.createObject` object. Any parameter you define there will be merged into the final mesh object of xeogl, and you may than access that parameter later using the default xeogl tools.

For example, I have this code when loading the gltf model:

```
handleNode: (function () {
                let objectCount = 0
                return function (nodeInfo, actions) {
                  if (nodeInfo.mesh !== undefined) {
                    // Node has a mesh
                    actions.createObject = {
                      id: model.commit.hash + '.' + objectCount++,
                      guid: nodeInfo.name,
                      entityType: 'ifc'
                    }
                  }
                  return true
                }
              })()
```

Look at the `entityType` property. I populate that with a fixed value, but it can also be dynamic info from the gltf node. It becomes part of the xeogl object so I can access it later.